# If writing a technical book, what's a "correct" way to write the manuscript and include graphs / charts / diagrams?

Tags: publishing

Typically I would use LaTex for a journal, but if you were submitting a manuscript to a publisher, what's an appropriate tool/method?

I ask, because textbooks don't usually appear like they are LaTex driven.  Getting started on the process, I'd hate to do something that would involve a lot of re-work down the line.

Comment: I made a small contribution to a book about modal logic (some figures and bibliography), and it was written in LaTeX. I can't say how common it is, but it is at least used sometimes. The safest bet is of course to ask your publisher before starting, but that's assuming you already have one.

Comment: related question: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/9875/using-latex-with-publishers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the publisher. If you have a publisher in mind, it may be best to just ask them.

Some examples:
[**Sage Publishing**](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/manuscript-submission-guidelines#LATEX) welcomes LaTeX submissions
[**ASCE**](https://ascelibrary.org/doi/pdf/10.1061/9780784478998) on the other hand does not, they want MS word with MathType
[**CRC Press**](https://tandfbis.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rt-files/AUTHOR/Guidelines/Camera+Ready+guide.pdf) also supports LaTeX

I haven't been able to find it for every publisher I tried, but with some digging you can find it half the time.